# scrollTo, scrollBy, smoothScrollTo, smoothScrollTo don't work in ScrollView after adding view in child layout

Tags: android, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I have HorizontalScrollView with child Layout inside. After adding view into child layout I can't scroll HorizontalScrollView to the right side of scroller.

scrollTo, scrollBy, smoothScrollTo, smoothScrollTo don't work.

Comment: Some sample code and in particular what sort of 'child Layout' you've added to the HorizontalScrollView might help somebody explain your problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

solved:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);

        final HorizontalScrollView hsv = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.hsv);
        OnGlobalLayoutListener listener = new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                hsv.scrollTo(100, 0);
            }
        };
        ll.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener);
```