# ScrollView over the tabhost

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I am creating a page that has tabhost (main) and each tabweight also has tabhost (child) but when I put  tabhost (child) inside scrollview its scroll works fine but it start from below the tabweight not from top of the page. I also try

```
         sView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
```

But page always load from below the tabweight.

Its screenshot like this when open MyDiet tab.

[image]

But I want it open like this

[image]

Suggest me any idea.
Thanks In advance.

Comment: Try adding a fake `View` with focusable and click-able property before Tabs.

Comment: Did you tried calling ScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0,0) after the element has been inflated (not in onCreate, look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696793/scrollto-scrollby-smoothscrollto-smoothscrollto-dont-work-in-scrollview-afte)

Answer (score 0):

You should give a little bit top margin of the layout:-

[image]

like as:-

< LinearLayout android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

>

i think this will work. If still problem then you  should send your xml code.